# update one table values in html form that are dependent on another table

Tags: php, mysql

Two tables Order and Line_items are Relate with each other as order_id is placed in line items,

now first populate the order table and then lineitems table on the base of order table's id.
All of the heppening in one isset() has two functions one add values in orders table and second function take order id and then populate the lineitems function.

Problems is for the very first lineitems the order id is "" in Html form's value attribute of order_id. (very hard for me to explain this problem).

Here is my Php `isset()` function.

```
 if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $shipping_address = $_POST['shipping_address'];
    $billing_address = $_POST['billing_address'];
    $shipping_method_id = $_POST['shipping_method_id'];
    $grand_total = $_POST['grand_total'];
$order->addOrder($user_id,$shipping_address,$billing_address,$shipping_method_id,$grand_total);

$order_id = $_POST['latestorder'];
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
$product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$product_quantity = $_POST['product_quantity'];
$product_total = $_POST['product_total'];
if (empty($order_id)) {
        $order_id=$order->latestOrderRecord();
        $order_id=+1;
    }


$id= count($product_id);

for ($i=0; $i <$id ; $i++) { 

    $line_items->insertInLineItems($order_id,$product_id[$i],$product_price[$i],$product_quantity[$i],$product_total[$i]);
    // $shoping_cart->

    header('location:../cart.php');

    }


}
```

html form

```
<form method="post" action="n/GetPostData.php" class="woocommerce-shipping-calculator">
  <td data-title="Shipping">
    Flat Rate: 
    <span class="amount">$300.00</span> 
    <p><a data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="calculator" href="#calculator" aria-expanded="false" class="shipping-calculator-button">Calculate Shipping</a></p>
    <div id="calculator" class="shipping-calculator-form collapse">
      <p id="calc_shipping_country_field" class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <select rel="calc_shipping_state" class="country_to_state" id="calc_shipping_country" name="shipping_method_id">
          <option>Select Shipment Method</option>
          <?php $shipping_method=$shipment_method->allShipmentMethod(); 
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($shipping_method)) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </p>
      <p id="calc_shipping_country_field" class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <input type="text" id="calc_shipping_postcode" name="shipping_address" placeholder="Shipping Address"  class="input-text">
      </p>
      <p id="calc_shipping_state_field" class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required">
        <input type="text" id="calc_shipping_postcode" name="billing_address" placeholder="Billing Address"  class="input-text">
      </p>
    </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="order-total">
    <th>Total</th>
    <td data-title="Total">
      <strong><span class="amount">$<?php echo $total; ?></span></strong> 
      <input type="hidden" name="grand_total" value="<?php echo $total ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
      <?php $latestrecord=$order->latestOrderRecord(); ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="latestorder" value="<?php echo $latestrecord ?>">
      <?php $total=0; $all_cart_products=$shoping_cart->allShopingcartValue($id); 
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_cart_products)) { ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="product_quantity[]" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="product_price[]" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="product_total[]" value="<?php echo $row['total']; ?>">
      <?php } ?>
      <p><button type="submit" class="button" name="check_out" type="submit">Chcek Out</button></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

for the very first time when order table is empty the `name="latestorder"` show "" (no value).

Here is `latestOrderRecord()` function definition

```
public function latestOrderRecord()
{

    $query="SELECT MAX(id) AS LatestRecord FROM orders";

    $conn=$this->Connection();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows>0) {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $latestrecord=$row['LatestRecord'];
         }
    }
    return $latestrecord;
}
```

[image: Line items table]

[image: Orders table Picture]

Comment: `latestOrderRecord()` where you defined?

Comment: it is define is a separate class let me edit my question

Comment: so question is that you are not getting values in `$latestrecord` ?? in hidden input?

Comment: for the very first time when there is no value in table. i dont get the value. and i need that value to store the lineitems,

Comment: this will give you `Undefined variable $latestrecord` for the very first time when you dont have anything in your table.

Comment: for the very first time when there is no value in table. i dont get the value. and i need that value to store the lineitems, now if i add the order_id value manually, that order id dont exist in orders table but in lineitems table. let me add screen shots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196325/discussion-between-devpro-and-ali-raza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that, you are using `header()` redirection inside your `for()` loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i <$id ; $i++) { 
    header('location:../cart.php'); // that is the issue 
}
```

You must need to use a variable for success in for loop, then you can use it outside the loop for redirection, something like:

**HINT:**

```
if($success){
    header('location:../cart.php');
    exit(); // always use exit() after header() otherwise script execution will not stop
}
```

**Edit:**

As per your comment, you are getting order id 0 in `lineitem` table, because you are inserting `$_POST['latestorder']` value which is 0 because you dont have latest ID.

you need to insert the last inserted id of this query:

```
$order->addOrder($user_id,$shipping_address,$billing_address,$shipping_method_id,$grand_total);
```

return last inserted id from `addOrder()` method, and store it into a new variable and use this variable in your `lineitem` table something like:

```
$lastInsertID = $order->addOrder($user_id,$shipping_address,$billing_address,$shipping_method_id,$grand_total);
```

and, here `$line_items->insertInLineItems($order_id,$product_id[$i],$product_price[$i],$product_quantity[$i],$product_total[$i]);` replace `$order_id` with `$lastInsertID`

Make sure, method `addOrder()` returns last inserted ID.

Comment: Same problems, order id is still 0 in lineitems table, and 4 in orders table

Comment: How do i do this `you need to insert the last inserted id of this query`

Comment: can we have this conversation after Nimaz(aser)?

Comment: @AliRaza: sure same to u

Comment: i did as you ask, i create a new function, that will return the id of table and i save that id in the lineitems table :) Thank you very much Allah apky knowledge main berkat daly Ameen

Comment: @AliRaza: JAZAKALLAH khair :)

Comment: seems problem is there, should we move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196333/discussion-between-devpro-and-ali-raza).